# What is $e, \pi, \ln 2,...$ etc in p adic?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

What is $e, \pi, \ln 2,...$ etc in p adic? And how to flip digits of decimal points? Does p-adic have their own constants? 10 adic base.

Comment: Could anyone give the first (or last, with p-adic it's hard to know what language to use) few digits for an example? Perhaps even a possible sequence that describes e.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4213789/96384

Answer (score 6):

The $p$-adic logarithm function and $p$-adic exponential function [have been defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_exponential_function). The value of $\ln 2$ can be worked out, although it's a little tricky. The value of $e$ itself can't be worked out, I don't think - the series doesn't converge there - but $e^p$ can, for example.

I don't know if there is a $p$-adic analogue of $\pi$.

Comment: [This](http://mathoverflow.net/a/24753/40804) mathoverflow answer claims that there's a $p$-adic analogue of $2\pi i$. I have my doubts it's what the OP is looking for, but it's the best thing I can remember to a $p$-adic analogue of $\pi$.

Comment: It's possible that the OP meant to ask about the $p$-ary decimal-like expansions of these constants, in which case yes, all real numbers have such expansions in any base, prime or not.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense (especially coming from the "$10$-adic base" bit)